# Querying 2 indexes of 2 different tables with Sphinx

Tags: sphinx

I've been trying to get sphinx to search 2 tables by linking 2 indexes. here are the sources of these indexes:

```
source gSrc 
{ #General Source
type                    = mysql

sql_host        = localhost
sql_user        = (blahblahblah)
sql_pass        = (blahblahblah)
sql_db          = (blahblahblah)
sql_port        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

sql_ranged_throttle = 0
}

source mentionActivitySrc : gSrc
{
sql_query       = \
    SELECT id, author, thesis, body, created, updated \
    FROM activity

sql_attr_uint       = id
sql_attr_timestamp  = updated

sql_query_info      = SELECT * FROM activity WHERE id=$id
}

source mentionUserSrc : gSrc
{
sql_query       = \
    SELECT id, first, last, username, email, updated \
    FROM user

sql_attr_uint       = id
sql_attr_timestamp  = updated

sql_query_info      = SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=$id
}
```

and here are the indexes themselves:

```
index gIndex
{ #General Index
docinfo         = extern
mlock           = 0
morphology      = none
min_word_len        = 1
charset_type        = sbcs
html_strip      = 0
}

index activityMentionIndex : gIndex 
{
source          = mentionActivitySrc
path            = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/activityMentionIndex
}

index userMentionIndex : gIndex 
{
source          = mentionUserSrc
path            = /var/lib/sphinxsearch/data/userMentionIndex
}
```

I'm using [sphinxapi.php](http://code.google.com/p/sphinxsearch/source/browse/trunk/api/sphinxapi.php?r=2014), and when I do

```
->query('some keywords', 'activityMentionIndex userMentionIndex');
```

the fields index of the returned array shows that it has only recognized the second index (in this case, the userMentionIndex, if I switch them, it will recognize the activityMentionIndex)

Can anybody tell me what I may be doing wrong, or if it's possible to query 2 indexes of 2 different tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it has searched both indexes. Just that

1) Document-IDs need to be unique. So if a document in the second index has the same id in first, only the second will show in the results. To get round this you need to arrange for the ids to be unique.

2) It doesnt try to merge the field lists (nor attributes for that matter) - it just uses the last one. The normal way to search multiple index is to use the same fieldnames (eg in a main+delta) so it doesnt actully matter.

--

Also your

```
 sql_attr_uint       = id
```

is erroneous. It shoudn't be there. The document id is automatic - its always the first column in the mysql resultset. Sphinx shuold be smart enough to just ignore it completely, but it best to remove it to avoid confusion.